# Using udf is throwing classNotFoundException in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am using UDF with a simple function:

```
val upper: String => String = _.toUpperCase
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val upperUDF = udf(upper)
dataset.withColumn("upper", upperUDF(col('text')).show
```

But getting the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   $line20.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$4
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1859)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1745)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2033)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
>   at

Comment: Are you intentionally naming your UDF the same as built-in SparkSQL `upper` function https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#upper? Seems like it creates endless recursion...

Comment: the code itself runs fine, probabely you have wrong dependencies, scala version etc?

Comment: I am using spark version 1.5.1